# How to draw dots on image view for all dimensions in android as shown in below image?

Tags: android, xml

I tried with this code but its not working on all dimensions screen. Is there any other way to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/diabetic_foot_left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</Linear layout>

<View
        android:id="@+id/view_lf_sensatiion1green"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

circle_green.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp">

    <solid
        android:color="#00ff00"/>

    <size
        android:width="2dp"
        android:height="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

i want to place dots on the image like below

[image]

I tried with this code but its not working on all dimensions screen. Is there any other way to do this.please help me i am new to android.

Comment: pre-draw the dots on the images, and use images with drawn dots.

Comment: I have the same requirement in my new project. Do you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas). You can draw images on top of others dynamically, creating [custom drawings](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing)

Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap foot = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.diabetic_foot_left);
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);

    Bitmap over = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle_green);
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(over, canvas.getWidth(), 
    canvas.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same requirement in my project. This is how i solved it.

1. Take a FrameLayout with fixed width and height.
2. In this FrameLayout, put image(in your case foot image) using ImageView.
3. Take one more FrameLayout to arrange circles on it. Align these circles by giving marginLeft, marginTop etc.
4. So this FrameLayout with fixed width and height acts as a container for image and circles.
5. As container width, height is fixed; this solution works for all device configurations.

i hope it would be helpful to few people.